# Parse all values from a XML element using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script

I am trying to parse forex values (all of them) for http://indicador.eof.cl/rss XML feed into a Gooogle Sites trough Google Apps Script.

The script as follow>

```
function doGet(){

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://indicador.eof.cl/rss").getContentText();
  var parsedResponse = Xml.parse(response, false);
  var root = parsedResponse.getElement();
  var entries = root.getElement('channel').getElements("item");

  for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
      var e = entries[i];
      var title = e.getElement("title").getText();
      var description = e.getElement("description").getText();
  }

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var TopVar = app.createHorizontalPanel();

  TopVar.add(app.createLabel(title).setStyleAttribute("fontSize","12px"));  
  TopVar.add(app.createLabel(description).setStyleAttribute("fontSize","12px"));

  app.add(TopVar);
  return app;
}
```

The issue is the code just bring me the first value no all of them, what i am forgetting?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move `TopVar.add(...);` lines inside for loop :

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
var TopVar = app.createHorizontalPanel();

for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
  var e = entries[i];
  var title = e.getElement("title").getText();
  var description = e.getElement("description").getText();
  TopVar.add(app.createLabel(title).setStyleAttribute("fontSize","12px"));  
  TopVar.add(app.createLabel(description).setStyleAttribute("fontSize","12px"));
}
```

Actually, I know nothing about google-apps-script. But your current code logic seems a bit off. It doesn't make use of values of local variables declare inside for loop (`e`, `title`, and `description`). Value of those variables changed in every iteration without any code using it.

Comment: Thank you very much it work.

Additional question, how can i optimize this code to extract just a few forex values from XML feed?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help further since this possibly platform specific question. I know how to do it in C# (*something like e.getElements('item').Where(some-criteria-here)*), but not in javascript/gas platform. Consider to post another question, so that other member with more expertise in js/gas can help you.